# Creating array from list of files in folder structure - PHP

Tags: php, scandir

I've been trying to sort through a whole bunch of folders, but have been unable to get multi-levels working the way I want.

I have a whole bunch of MP4 files, scattered through out a multi-level directory structure, and I need to get an array with just the list of folders that have MP4 files inside them.

So here is a list of folders and files for example.

```
/videos/
/videos/2015-11-09/
/videos/2015-11-09/device-1/
/videos/2015-11-09/device-1/110519/
/videos/2015-11-09/device-1/110519/Video-001.MP4
/videos/2015-11-09/device-1/110519/Video-002.MP4
/videos/2015-11-09/device-1/134852/Video-003.MP4
/videos/2015-11-09/device-2/
/videos/2015-11-09/device-2/094516/
/videos/2015-11-09/device-2/094516/Video-001.MP4
/videos/2015-11-09/device-2/094516/Video-002.MP4
/videos/2015-11-10/
/videos/2015-11-10/device-1/
/videos/2015-11-10/device-1/214537/Video-004.MP4
/videos/2015-11-10/device-1/214537/Video-005.MP4
/videos/2015-11-10/device-4/
/videos/2015-11-10/device-4/Video02-001.MP4
/videos/2015-11-10/device-4/Video02-002.MP4
/videos/2015-11-10/Video01-001.MP4
/videos/2015-11-10/Video01-002.MP4
/videos/2015-11-10/Video01-003.MP4
```

I want a php function to look through these, using scandir().

I have built a few functions to remove hidden files, and also everything else but .MP4 from the results.

```
$HiddenFileFilter = function($a) {
    return $a[0] != ".";
};

$FileFilter = function($a) {
    if (strpos($a,'.MP4') !== false) {
        return $a;
    }
};

$ScandirFilteredResults = array_filter(scandir($Dir), $FileFilter);
```

The results I want are the directories that have .MP4 files inside them, and the MP4 files, also having the filemtime() will be good for each folder.

```
Array (
    [/videos/2015-11-09/device-1/110519/] => Array (
        [filemtime] => FILE_M_TIME
        [MP4] => Array (
            [0] => Video-001.MP4
            [1] => Video-002.MP4
        )
    )
    [/videos/2015-11-09/device-1/134852/] => Array (
        [filemtime] => FILE_M_TIME
        [MP4] => Array (
            [0] => Video01-003.MP4
        )
    )
    [/videos/2015-11-09/device-2/094516/] => Array (
        [filemtime] => FILE_M_TIME
        [MP4] => Array (
            [0] => Video-001.MP4
            [1] => Video-002.MP4
        )
    )
    [/videos/2015-11-10/device-1/214537/] => Array (
        [filemtime] => FILE_M_TIME
        [MP4] => Array (
            [0] => Video01-004.MP4
            [1] => Video01-005.MP4
        )
    )
    [/videos/2015-11-10/device-4/] => Array (
        [filemtime] => FILE_M_TIME
        [MP4] => Array (
            [0] => Video02-001.MP4
            [1] => Video02-002.MP4
        )
    )
    [/videos/2015-11-09/] => Array (
        [filemtime] => FILE_M_TIME
        [MP4] => Array (
            [0] => Video01-001.MP4
            [1] => Video01-002.MP4
            [2] => Video01-003.MP4
        )
    )
)
```

I want only the folders that have .MP4 files inside to be in the output array along with the MP4 files inside them.

There may be directories 6 levels down, that need to be listed. So anything in /videos/.

I have been able to build a function to do this for a all videos in the third folder down, but I don't know how to do it for folders at multiple levels.

Comment: create a recursive function that builds the array?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a recursive function to scan the directory recursively.

Try the following code. Code is commented wherever necessary.

```
$all_mp4_files = ScandirRecursive($Dir);
print_r($all_mp4_files);


function ScandirRecursive($Dir){
    $file_list = array();
    $ScandirFilteredResults = scandir($Dir);
    foreach ($ScandirFilteredResults as $file){
        if ($file[0] !='.'){
            $full_file_name = $Dir . '/' .$file;
            if (is_dir($full_file_name)){ // if this is a directory scan the files inside it.
                // merge the sub directory with current
                $file_list = array_merge($file_list, ScandirRecursive($full_file_name));
            }else{
                if (strtoupper(pathinfo($full_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'MP4'){
                    //Build your array
                    $file_list[dirname($full_file_name)]['filemtime'][] = filemtime($full_file_name);
                    $file_list[dirname($full_file_name)]['MP4'][] = basename($full_file_name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $file_list;
}
```

Note: The code is not tested and is just a guide for you to build.